# How to create a sticky header that spans more than one section

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view where each cell is a section. I need to implement a "sticky header" that will span say 3 sections, until another "sticky header" replaces it. How can I do this? I can't change my cells to all share the same section for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I will demonstrate how to do it for the first section only. It's quite immature because some constants are used.  However, if you follow the pattern , you can achieve your goal much easier.

To achieve high precision, please change the code as you like.

Basically, just subclass the UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

```
class MyCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout{

lazy var offset : CGFloat? = { return self.collectionView?.contentOffset.y}()

// only first section here, you need to add other sections programmatically later.
override func invalidationContext(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext{
   let result =   super.invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: newBounds)
   result.invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)])
    return result
}


  override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?{
  let result =  super.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: elementKind, at: indexPath)
    guard indexPath.section % 3 == 0 else {
        return result
    }
    let section = CGFloat (indexPath.section / 3)

    let   totalHeight : CGFloat =  414.0 +  1390.0 * (section)  //414 = first section height
    // 1390 = height of three sections
    let   totalNextHight : CGFloat = 1390.0 * (section + 1)

    if let result = result {
    if result.frame.origin.y >  CGFloat(totalHeight) {
          result.frame = CGRect.init(x: result.frame.origin.x , y:  (result.frame.origin.y < totalNextHight) ? (self.collectionView?.contentOffset.y)! - offset! + totalHeight : totalNextHight, width: result.frame.width, height: result.frame.height)

        }
    }
    return result
}
```

As I said, this is only works for the first sticky header. I defined the header size in delegate like this :

```
extension MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize{
    if section % 3 == 0  {return CGSize.init(width:200 , height: 44)}
    return CGSize.init(width:0 , height: 0)
   }
```

}

There is a lot of work behind these codes. Hope you find your own answer to the question soon.